# Load and parse remote url with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, url, greasemonkey

How can I write a Greasemonkey script that will go through a list of URLs (on the same domain) and enable an XPath query to be performed on the resulting DOM?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use [GM_xmlhttpRequest](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) for the request, and createContextualFragment for HTML parsing.   See [Best Addons for Greasemonkey](http://michkhoo.blogspot.com/2009/08/some-addons-for-greasemonkey.html) for an example using createContextualFragment. For parsing of valid XML you can just use [DOMParser.parseFromString](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOMParser).

EDIT: Here's a very simple but complete example to show how everything fits together:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Parse HTML demo
// @namespace
// @include        *
// ==/UserScript==

GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    onload: function(resp){
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStartAfter(document.body);
    var xhr_frag = range.createContextualFragment(resp.responseText);
    var xhr_doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, 'html', null);
    xhr_doc.adoptNode(xhr_frag);
    xhr_doc.documentElement.appendChild(xhr_frag);
    var node = xhr_doc.evaluate("//span//b[@class='gb1']", xhr_doc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    GM_log("node.localName: " + node.localName);
    GM_log("node.textContent: " + node.textContent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with xml or well written xhtml, you could do as follows:

```
// XMLDocument
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xhr.responseText, "text/xml");
```

Otherwise:

```
// HTMLDocument
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
doc.documentElement.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
```

Once you have the document, you may use anything just like a normal document.