# Greasemonkey: load url using GM_xmlhttpRequest and createContextualFragment

Tags: greasemonkey

I have the following GreaseMonkey Script:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
     method: 'GET',
     url: "http://www.testurl.com",
     headers: {
         'User-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible) Greasemonkey/0.3',
     },
     onload: function(responseDetails) {

   var tagString = responseDetails.responseText;       
   var range = document.createRange();
   range.selectNode(document.body);
   var documentFragment = range.createContextualFragment(tagString);
```

How do I now extract stuff from documentFragment? documentFragment.getElementById(''), document.body etc all returns undefined.

I suspect this is due to the createContextualFragment method returning a XPCNativeWrapper object, but how do I work around this to access the underlying DOM?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is answered by [Load and parse remote url with greasemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211430/load-and-parse-remote-url-with-greasemonkey)

Depending what you want to do, might be easier to include jquery..

Comment: haha, only just noticed that was another of your questions :D

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect this is due to the
>   createContextualFragment method
>   returning a XPCNativeWrapper object,
>   but how do I work around this to
>   access the underlying DOM?

This is done using [wrappedJSObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPConnect_wrappers#XPCSafeJSObjectWrapper):

```
var documentFragment = range.createContextualFragment(tagString).wrappedJSObject;
```